# Get a big List<T> from WCF in chunks?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to get a list of entities from a WCF service, the problem I'm experiencing is that we have some bad latency on the network and so the data takes a considerable amount of time to get to my client. The idea I have is to find a way to get the first 1000 and just push those to the UI while I'm waiting for the next ones to arrive.

I guess it would be like paging but I just want to page the full set in the WCF layer rather that get one page at a time from the db

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end as I'm using tcpTransport for my communication, I ended using duplex channels to do what I needed.

What I did is just change my current SearchMethod that was returning a big list to void. Inside this method I get my data from the DB, chunk it and send it to the client via a callback operation

Answer (score 6):

WCF looks at the message at its entirety before handing it to higher levels. Hence your data needs to arrive in full and usual WCF contracts will not work.

However, you can use [streaming with WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx). This allows for the payload to be read gradually from the stream and be passed to the higher levels. In order to get it working you need to:

- enable streaming (in the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx) I provided)
- change service contract to provide a stream
- at server end, start serializing entities and writing to the stream, perhaps in 100 chunks. You need to serialize entities yourself although using DataContractSerializer our of the box is very simple.
- You need to provide a delimiter between each of these 100 entities so that your process could spot where current 100 is finished. One possible option is 1 KB of byte zero.
- at the client side, implement function as Async. Keep reading from the stream in buffers (e.g 4KB) until hit the delimiter. Once hit that, deserialize and raise async event.

This will **more complex** that WCF straight out of the box but achieves what you need.

Comment: No link again. I've just checked in IE 6 (Work pc) and I'm using Chrome. I was a bit worried it was the browser breaking something, but it's the same in both.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I am in fact off-sick and in bed so it must have been my problem :)

Comment: I think this is worth trying, I'll play a little and see how it goes, ideally I want to achieve something where this is abstracted and I don't need to worry at the client side about how this internally works

Comment: If you iplement streaming where you expose just a stream, then proxy needs to know. Although you can create a custom proxy where you encapsulate all deserialsation.

Answer (score 3):

You can always split your service interface into two methods. For example, instead of:

```
List<T> GetItems()
```

You can have:

```
int GetItemCount()

List<T> GetItems(int start, int maxSize)
```

So that you can implement paging manually.

Comment: What would be the best way to 'cache' this list in the Service side?

Comment: It depends on your persistence layer. For example, NHibernate will do the caching automatically, as long as you share the session across requests. (Actually it has a two layer cache, and many options). If you're using another framework, you should look into their documentation. If you're using SQL directly, it might be a good time to look at those.

Comment: We are using sql directly and switching is not an option, I already know the goodness of nhibernate but we have constraints enforced by our customer no to use it...